# The API handles a faulty request without raising an error eventhough annotated with ApiModelProperty with dataType

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-2.0, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am getting the following error - "The generated value is of the type integer instead of the type ‘string’" with 42crunch conformance scan with the following problem reported - "The API handles a faulty request without raising an error"

In the test scan, it is trying to pass the following request body -

```
{"type":1,"visitId":"xxxx","visitorId":"Ag5w\u0010l\u0014"}
```

So in above request, type is passed as integer but API is declared with type with "String" property.

```
  @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.lang.String", value = "Type", example = "Data")  
  @Pattern(regexp = "^.*$")
  @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
  private String type;
```

I have the above annotation for the input request class. So eventhough type property is declared with ApiModelProperty annotation with dataType accepting only "java.lang.String", why is it throwing error?

I also have the @Valid annotation for the controller endpoint method which is accepting the request body.

```
 public ResponseEnvelope recommendedProducts(   
          @Valid @RequestBody RecommendedProductRequest productRequest,
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
```

Please let know how to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

First things first ! , I am assuming you are using Springfox package for swagger. If that is the case , Then it is very important that you plan to move away from Springfox as soon as possible. We have an open vulnerability for **Cross Site Scripting (XSS)** in spring fox. Please refer the below link for further details. Also the support has been poor in recent years.

- https://security.snyk.io/package/maven/io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui

Now coming to your issue. Have you tried providing an sample value for 42Crunch to take while performing conformance scan ?. For a fact we have tried giving example values in OpenAPI implementations and it worked like charm. But i am not too sure about the how to pass sample values for 42Crunch in SpringFox implementation. However i found the following snippet. Try this if 42Crunch performs scan with the provided value. Further i have taken a look at the 42Crunch docs and found this part ( Checkout the **Providing examples** section in the below link )

https://docs.42crunch.com/latest/content/concepts/api_contract_conformance_scan.htm

But again its better to move to OpenAPI documentation. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Conformance Scan by 42Crunch does automatic contract conformance testing. In other words, it checks if your API conforms to the constraints of its OpenAPI contract.

In your example, the data parameter is defined to accept String type only.
So to verify your API implementation, Conformance Scan sends a request using a type other than String (similar to what a hacker might do to probe your API for vulnerabilities).

If well implemented, your API *should* return an appropriate error for a request that does not match the constraints.

Based on the snippet you shared: "The API handles a faulty request without raising an error", it suggests your API did not reject an invalid request (it should).

The recommended solution would be to ensure your API rejects invalid requests that do not match the parameter constraints.